# Hartshorne Chapter II Theorem 5.19

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, $S$ is a graded ring with $S_0=A$. Let $X=\operatorname{Proj}S$, define $S'$ to be $\oplus_{n\geq 0}\Gamma(X, O_X(n))$.

Then in the theorem, Hartshorne claimed $S'$ is integral over $S$. He showed that for every $s'\in S'$ and for every $q \geq 1$, we have $(s')^q \in (1/{{x_0}^n})S$ for some large enough $n$. Then Hartshorne said this is a finitely generated sub-$S$-module of the quotient field of $S'$, it follows by a well-known criterion for integral dependence (in Atiyah-Macdonald page 59) that $s'$ is integral over $S$.

I think he was referring to *'$x\in B$ is integral over $A$ if and only if $A[x]$ is contained in a subring $C$ of $B$ such that $C$ is a finitely generated $A$-module'* from Atiyah-Macdonald. However I am confused because I think $(1/{{x_0}^n})S$ is not a ring.

Comment: You may want to see item iv) on p. 60.